# Asynchronous KeyboardInterrupt and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, signals

It seems that asynchronous signals in multithreaded programs are not correctly handled by Python. But, I thought I would check here to see if anyone can spot a place where I am violating some principle, or misunderstanding some concept.

There are similar threads I've found here on SO, but none that seem to be quite the same.

The scenario is: I have two threads, reader thread and writer thread (main thread). The writer thread writes to a pipe that the reader thread polls. The two threads are coordinated using a `threading.Event()` primitive (which I assume is implemented using `pthread_cond_wait`). The main thread waits on the `Event` while the reader thread eventually sets it.

But, if I want to interrupt my program while the main thread is waiting on the `Event`, the KeyboardInterrupt is not handled asynchronously.

Here is a small program to illustrate my point:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import select
import time
import threading

pfd_r = -1
pfd_w = -1
reader_ready = threading.Event()

class Reader(threading.Thread):
    """Read data from pipe and echo to stdout."""
    def run(self):
        global pfd_r
        while True:
            if select.select([pfd_r], [], [], 1)[0] == [pfd_r]:
                output = os.read(pfd_r, 1000)
                sys.stdout.write("R> '%s'\n" % output)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                # Suppose there is some long-running processing happening:
                time.sleep(10)
                reader_ready.set()


# Set up pipe.
(pfd_r, pfd_w) = os.pipe()
rt = Reader()
rt.daemon = True
rt.start()

while True:
    reader_ready.clear()
    user_input = raw_input("> ").strip()
    written = os.write(pfd_w, user_input)
    assert written == len(user_input)
    # Wait for reply -- Try to ^C here and it won't work immediately.
    reader_ready.wait()
```

Start the program with './bug.py' and enter some input at the prompt. Once you see the reader reply with the prefix 'R>', try to interrupt using `^C`.

What I see (Ubuntu Linux 10.10, Python 2.6.6) is that the `^C` is not handled until after the blocking `reader_ready.wait()` returns. What I expected to see is that the `^C` is raised asynchronously, resulting in the program terminating (because I do not catch KeyboardInterrupt).

This may seem like a contrived example, but I'm running into this in a real-world program where the `time.sleep(10)` is replaced by actual computation.

Am I doing something obviously wrong, like misunderstanding what the expected result would be?

Edit: I've also just tested with Python 3.1.1 and the same problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait()` method of a `threading._Event` object actually relies on a `thread.lock`'s `acquire()` method. However, the [thread documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) states that a lock's `acquire()` method cannot be interrupted, and that any `KeyboardInterrupt` exception will be handled after the lock is released.

So basically, this is working as intended. Threading objects that implement this behavior rely on a lock at some point (including queues), so you might want to choose another path.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. I might make the argument that this particular "feature" is in fact a bug.... I guess I'll have to figure out another way to synchronize my threads. It just seems silly that I can't use a built in synchronization primitive to do that.

Comment: Well you could go for the pretty hackish: `while 1:` (Line break)  `if reader_ready.wait(1): break`

Comment: I could do that, or use `reader_ready.wait(99999)` as the timeout. It seems to then do a `sleep` occasionally, and so the keyboard interrupt can be handled then. Still, a hack.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the timeout actually didn't matter after posting this comment. I agree with your comment nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use the `pause()` function of the [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.pause) module instead of `reader_ready.wait()`. `signal.pause()` is a blocking function and gets unblocked when a signal is received by the process. In your case, when `^C` is pressed, SIGINT signal unblocks the function.

According to the documentation, the function is not available for Windows. I've tested it on Linux and it works. I think this is better than using `wait()` with a timeout.